# Linear layout background drawable is not visible when changing background color of textview

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/search_et_container_bottom_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/search_result_header_background"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/institute_tab_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height48"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="@color/learnito_red"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/institutes"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size18" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/course_tab_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height48"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/courses"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size18" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When TextView is clicked I am chaging the background color to simulate a tabbed kind of layout.

```
    mTab1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    mTab1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mTab2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mTab2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

But the background drawable for linear layout disappears when trying to set the background color.

Comment: how you will see something which behind some opaque thing. linear layout height is wrap content so it will be of same height as textview and when you change color of your textview if it was previously transparent you will not see the linear layout behind

Comment: why don't you use selector?

Comment: its working fine fr me :-s

Comment: Because you have set the height as wrap_content hence it will only wrap the layouts inside it and as you are setting both the textViws an opaque color